# json schema to validate required label

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Im using json schema draft-4 and I am trying to conditionally add a requirement for a required label.  For any value in env labels 1/2/3 are required but if the value is sit or uat then another label, date must also be required.

```
    "date": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "not": {
        "properties": { "env": { "enum": ["sit", "uat"] } },
        "required": ["label1","label2","label3]
        }
    },
    { "required": ["date"] }
  ],
```

Ive based what I have on Implications documented here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals

**2nd Try**

```
"labels": {
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": [
      "string",
      "null"
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "label1": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "number"
      ]
    },
    "label2": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    "label3": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "label1",
    "label2",
    "label3"
  ],
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "date"
      ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "env": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "sit",
            "uat"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "date"
        ]
      },
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "env": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "dev",
            "prod"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

**Results / Expected Result
Test 1**

- env: sit or uat
- date: 2024-01-01
- Result: Pass
- ER: Pass

**Test 2**

- env: sit or uat
- (date label not passed)
- Result: Pass
- ER: Fail

**Test 3**

- env: dev or prod
- (date label not passed)
- Result: Pass
- ER: Pass

Comment: can `date` be provided even if the `env` is not `sit` or `uat`?

Comment: I don't want date to exist if env is not sit or uat.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would solve this using the Implication Pattern. This approach is more efficient and has better error messaging than other options.

Because implication isn't particularly easy to read, I've also shown how I like to organize schemas to make this easier to read. First, I declare all the properties at the top level. Then, I deal with complex assertions. I like to declare anything complex in a definition with a descriptive name and then reference it after the basic declarations. This pattern scales to as many complex assertions you need, just add more definition references to the `allOf`. This approach makes schemas easier to read because it abstracts the complicated parts. You only need to dig into the complicated parts if you're debugging that specific part.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "env": { ... },
    "label1": { ... },
    "label2": { ... },
    "label3": { ... },
    "date": { ... }
  },
  "required": ["label1", "label2", "label3"],

  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/sit-uat-requires-date" }],

  "definitions": {
    "sit-uat-requires-date": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "not": {
            "properties": {
              "env": { "enum": ["sit", "uat"] }
            },
            "required": ["env"]
          }
        },
        { "required": ["date"] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Missing closing bracket on `date`.  Nice one!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tested this but when env is set to prod it complains date not found, I dont want a date setting for prod. @jason

Comment: @user3460417 Sorry! I forgot the `not` in the implication pattern. Answer has been edited with the correction (including fixing the typo, thanks Jeremy).

Answer (score 0):

This will satisfy your requirements.

if `date` is only allowed with `sit` and `uat` then you can modify this slightly to constrain `date` from the `required` array in the second `oneOf` schema.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "required": [
        "env",
        "label1",
        "label2",
        "label3"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "env": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "label1": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "label2": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "label3": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "required": [
                "date",
                "env"
            ],
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "env": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "sit",
                        "uat"
                    ]
                },
                "date": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "not": {  <-- optional depending on your `date` requirement
                "required": [
                    "date"
                ]
            },
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "env": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "dev",
                        "prod"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've tried to simplify your code, maybe incorrectly but this isnt erroring that 'date' does not exist for dev:

"oneOf": [
        {
          "required": ["date"],
          "properties": { "env": { "enum": ["sit","uat"] } }
       },
        {
          "not": { "required": ["date"] },
          "properties": { "env": { "enum": ["dev","prod"] } }
        }
      ],

Comment: What are you trying to simplify?  It looks like you removed the `type` definitions. Any particular reason?

Comment: It seems like it may be easier to read but in fact, it changes the validation output when the type definition is removed.  Here's an example  `{
"env": "sit",
"label1": "1",
"label2": "2",
"label3": "3",
"date": 1
}`

if you remove the `type` definition, the schema is not constrained to ONLY `type: string` and further constrained by the `enum` defined because the keyword `enum` only applies to a string instance.  If we pass a number/integer to `date`, the value is not a string and the `enum` will not evaluate the `date` property as expected.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the code updates you mentioned and the result / expected result. For some reason it's still not validating sit / uat correctly i.e. If sit / uat is used then date label is required.  @Jeremy

Comment: i'm very curious to know which validator you are using.  both options I provided are passing your expectations from what I understand of them.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this would be to redefine the entire schema in a `oneOf`

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "required": [
                "date",
                "env",
                "label1",
                "label2",
                "label3"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "date": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "env": {
                    "enum": [
                        "sit",
                        "uat"
                    ]
                },
                "label1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "label2": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "label3": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "required": [
                "env",
                "label1",
                "label2",
                "label3"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "env": {
                    "enum": [
                        "prod",
                        "dev"
                    ]
                },
                "label1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "label2": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "label3": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```